# How to render templates into templates with IronRouter and Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, iron-router

I read many posts on this, including a [good tutorial](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/iron-router-tutorial) but I still cannot find what is wrong with my code. My intention is to configure the web page I am designing to be able to work with Iron Router.

It basically displays a number of pictures with captions and, when the user selects one, a message is displayed in a new template and format (that is why I need Iron Router).

I am facing trouble in setting it up: the ApplicationLayout template should render the boost template for each user so all his/her pictures are displayed. However, when it is displayed, I get the html for body.html but not the one in  boost.html.

The Java Script helpers and event handlers work fine; I have checked for that already. That is why I only include the code for body.html, boost.html and routes.js. Please note that the code corresponds to three different files:
both html files are in the same folder (ui) and the js file is in the lib folder, all inside my project's directory.

Thanks in advance!

**body.html**

```
<template name="ApplicationLayout">
    <body>
    {{> sAlert}}
        <div id="background">
        <img src="http://s1.picswalls.com/wallpapers/2015/11/21/beautiful-motivation-wallpaper_10342177_288.jpg" class="stretch" alt="" />
    </div>
        <div class="container">
            <header>
                {{#if currentUser}}
                <h1>Your Boosts! ({{incompleteCount}})</h1>
                {{else}}
                <h1>Community Boosts!</h1>
                {{/if}}
                {{> undoRedoButtons}}

               {{> loginButtons}}

               {{#if currentUser}}
                <form class="new-boosts">
                    <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Type to add a short description"/>
                    <input type="text" name="image" accept = "image/*" placeholder="Type to add a picture url"/>
                    <input type="number" name="importance" min = "0" placeholder="Type to choose an importance position"/>
                    <textarea class = "text-area" name="message" rows = "10" cols = "5" placeholder="Type a message for yourself"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="new-boosts first">
                </form>
                {{/if}} 
            </header>
            <ul>
                {{#each boosts}}
                    {{> yield}}
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
    </template>
```

**boost.html**

```
    <template name="boost">

        <article class="image-with-header">
            <img class="image" src="{{image}}" />
        </article>

        <li class="{{#if private}}private{{/if}}">
            <button class="delete">&times;</button>

            {{#if isOwner}}
                <button class="toggle-private">
                {{#if private}}
                 Private
                {{else}}
                  Public
                {{/if}}
                </button>
            {{/if}}

            <span class="text"><strong>{{username}}</strong> - <input type="text" value="{{text}}" name="caption"> - <input type="number" value="{{importance}}" name="importance"> </span>
        </li>
    </template>
```

**routes.js**

```
Router.configure({
   layoutTemplate: 'ApplicationLayout'
});

Router.route('/', function () {
  this.layout('ApplicationLayout');
  this.render('boost');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are using `{{> yield}}` inside an `each` loop. Try this:

*.html

```
<template name="ApplicationLayout">
    <body>
      {{!-- ... --}}
          <ul>
            {{> yield}}
          </ul>
      {{!-- ... --}}
    </body>
</template>

<template name="boosts">
  {{#each boosts}}
      {{> boost}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="boost">
  {{!-- ... --}}
</template>
```

*.js

```
// in tempalte file
Template.boosts.helpers({
  boosts() {
    // return boosts here
  }
});

// in router file

Router.configure({
   layoutTemplate: 'ApplicationLayout'
});

Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('boosts');
});
```

Comment: That answered my question and the program now works. Nevertheless, I would be interested in understanding why the yield does not work in an each loop. @Khang would you by any chance know why Iron Router works like this? Or is it just arbitrary? Thanks!